# Multiple future method from Queueable Apex

Tags: apex, governorlimits, queueable-apex

As per the documentation we can only call 1 future from Queueable context.

[image]

But in below code I am able to call multiple future methods from same queueable class and no error is being thrown.

```apex
public with sharing class QueuableTest implements System.Queueable {
    public void execute(QueueableContext qc) {
        QueuableTest.future1();
        QueuableTest.future2();
        // Created future methods in another class
        // AccountTriggerHelper.future2();
        // AccountTriggerHelper.future3();
        System.debug('I am in queueable class');
    }
    @future
    public static void future1() {
        System.debug('Future 1');
    }
    @future
    public static void future2() {
        System.debug('future 2');
    }
}
```

On enqueuing above class I get 3 debug logs 2 for "future handler" and 1 for "Queueable handler".
Shouldn't it error out, because I am calling 2 future methods - but only 1 is allowed?

[image]

Comment: I was able to replicate this, and I don't see why... Interesting

Comment: I am also able to call more than 1 future method from queueable apex. Interesting

Comment: Its got be either a bug in apex or misleading documentation. I did some testing and  queueable apex seems to support up to 50 future methods calls per queueable apex invocation, which seems to be the same limit as # of future methods that can be called from a synchronous apex transaction. I try to run this from Salesforce support and try to get some answers.

Comment: I am thinking its mis-representation in documents. Support would be able to answer it better

Comment: Just checking if you already have a support case logged for this?

Comment: I have. Hopefully there should be some update from them soon.

Comment: @arut : Thanks for putting the effort and raising the case.

Comment: I have this on my radar and will let you know as I have more details. Thx

Comment: @Elijah Can you share the support case number please. Generally, this is a bug. Developers shouldn't rely on it. There is the potential to create async jobs that branch out rapidly and consume the entire async apex limit.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Case # is 42684295. I was hoping Salesforce apex team members active in SFSE to chime in here. Thanks.

Comment: Known issue created by Salesforce for this issue: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V00000214kJQAQ

Answer (score 0):

The reported scenario has been identified as an issue with how limits are enforced for future recursion. Our product development team(all thanks to @DanielBallinger ) has filed a bug #W-11247010 for this behaviour.

According to the filed bug, `Limits.getLimitFutureCalls()` is incorrectly returning 50 when called in a future method. Ideally, it should return 0 when called from a future method.

It indicates that a future method could be invoked. However, attempting to do so results in an System.AsyncException with the message:

> Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method

The exception is expected here, but the Limits class is returning a misleading value.

In contrast, the Limits.getLimitQueueableJobs() method returns the expected value of 1.

One plus side of this is that the future method itself can't be used to fan out the volume of async jobs. Only the Queueable to Future step permits that.

The below example future method that shows Limits.getLimitFutureCalls() returns 50 when System.isFuture() is true. The value should actually be 0 (zero) in this case.

```
// FutureTest.future1('base', 0);

public class FutureTest {
    @future
    public static void future1(string baseName, integer depth) {
        System.debug('Future 1 [' + baseName + '] Depth: ' + depth);
        System.debug('FutureCalls: ' + Limits.getFutureCalls() + '/' + Limits.getLimitFutureCalls() );
        System.debug('System.isFuture: ' + System.isFuture() );
        
        if(Limits.getLimitFutureCalls() > 0 && Limits.getFutureCalls() < Limits.getLimitFutureCalls()) {
            // This should be impossible from a Future method!
            // Throws Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method:...
            FutureTest.future1(baseName + ' > Future!1_' + depth, depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

We have also filed a bug #W-11261710 that Queueable execution can start 50 child @Future jobs.

Known issue link:  trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V00000214kJQAQ

Comment: Thanks @DanielBallinger & @Swetha for following-up. Sounds like the bug is not just related to `Limits.getLimitFutureCalls()` because if the platform were to depend on this value alone, then future recursion should also happen (which fortunately doesn't happen).

Comment: @arut We have also filed a bug #W-11261710 for investigating the present functionality that we can call more than one future method from a queueable context. This also includes having the documentation to reflect the current situation.

Comment: This bug tracking seems more relevant to this question. I guess these bug # are internal to SF product team and not one of those known issue identifiers.

Comment: That's correct! These are internal to the salesforce. I'll check if I can get a public-facing known issue created. Until then, can follow up for status using a support case with the bug reference number.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response

Comment: Maybe you want to add to your answer or post another answer: Instead of limiting the number of @future calls from Queueable, Salesforce has lifted the declared limit - which is great. Some bugs that just become "Working as Expected" are actually welcome ;-)